# FPGA basics and implementation help

Tags: microcontroller, fpga, programming, multiplexer

I want to use an FPGA for my project and I want to use an FPGA as I want to implement the functionality of **multiplexers** within it.

Also I want to implement a **microcontroller** function within an FPGA. I know this is possible but just wanted to be sure about it in the case of low cost FPGAs.

I have the following questions:

1. I also want to implement a Digital to Analog amplifier.
2. I want to use **100 FPGAs** and I want to know whether it is possible to have just a single programming board and program all these 100 FPGAs and then use them **standalone** in my PCB.

As FPGAs are cheap but the programming boards are very expensive.

3. Also I was unable to find **through-hole FPGAs**, can someone tell me that what is the maximum pin count through hole FPGA I can find, if I can find one.

Thanks for your suggestions.

Kind Regards.

Comment: Really? Just, no.

Comment: What is a "Digital to Analog **amplifier**"???

Comment: Doesn't make any sense to me, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

> through-hole FPGAs

I was going to say "there aren't any", but digikey surprised me: http://www.digikey.co.uk/product-detail/en/microsemi-corporation/APA600-CGS624M/APA600-CGS624M-ND/4294652

They're £4000 each, out of stock, and almost obsolete.

Realistically you'll have to use one of the surface mount QFP versions.

> As FPGAs are cheap but the programming boards are very expensive.

Usually the other way round. In production, you'll have the FPGA "boot" off a small EEPROM. These are in the $1 cost range.

> 100 FPGAs in my PCB

What, on the same colossal PCB? Are you sure?

> Digital to Analog amplifier

FPGA isn't the obvious choice for that project?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am sorry for the DAC question, I read somewhere that there's a possibility to implement it.

I have to use 100 FPGAs on 100 different PCBs, in short 1 FPGA per PCB and all the FPGAs will have the same function to perform.

And if I understood your question correctly, then I can use an external EEPROM and then use an FPGA.

For my project I have to use Muxs and need to control them through a microcontroller, need to apply certain voltage at the output pin of a mux. So I thought of using a single FPGA for performing both these tasks.

Is it possible?

Comment: It sounds like you're starting with a solution and trying to fit it to your problem. If you were to describe the context of what you were actually trying to build you might get better responses.

Comment: The project is to have 50 pins and apply the same current to these pins one by one. I can surely do this with a help of a Mux and a uC but I want to use an FPGA due to its flexibility.

Thanks

Comment: Controllable current? About how much current? FPGAs are not at all suitable for this - a digital mux replicates a logical value *not* an amount of current! You might be better off with regular transistors. (And you said "current" at one point and "voltage" at another. What's on the other end - what are you driving?)

Comment: Firstly, sorry for so many pestering questions.

Secondly, I just want to check whether the data is being transmitted from one end is being received at the other end.

As there are 50 pins on both ends, I want to see whether the bits being sent from one end are being received at the other end.

Hence, I want to use a microncotroller function within the FPGA to send bits from one end and then read at the other end.

Thats's my entire task.

Comment: One end of what? Do you care about having a specific current/voltage, or do you just want a logic bit? (This might be easier if you edit a description of the whole project into the question)

Comment: So you want to apply a voltage to one pin while holding 49 others low and verify that on the other end you see that voltage on a single pin but no others. You then want to repeat this on each pin. Do I have that correct? If so get rid of the mux, use shift registers on each end. And there is no need for a processor of any sort, that is the sort of thing a logic state machine can do without the need for any processor. A small PLD for the state machine and two chains of shift registers, one for input, one for output and you're done.

Comment: Exactly Andrew. That's what I want to do pjc50.

That's what I want to do. But can you explain a bit more that how can I use the shift registers. No clue about that. And how can I do that without the processor.

I thought using an FPGA would give more flexibility. Also it gives an option of implementing controller and muxes. But I am completely open to your idea and thanks for it.

Comment: The flexibility of FPGA is really a cost here: if you're not familiar with shift registers, it'll take you months to get something working on an FPGA.

Comment: I have theoretical knowledge and working idea of Shift registers but have never actually worked with them.
And time limit is not a constraint for me.

Comment: How to do it without a processor? Rather than writing a processor in VHDL (which is hard) and then code for the test in assembly (also hard, a c compiler for a tiny custom mirco is hard to find) you write the code for the test in VHDL (which is a lot easier than a processor to write). All you need to do is basic counting and comparisons, that's fairly simple to implement in logic as a state machine. Do some reading and then ask another question, comments aren't the place to go into details.

Comment: Yes Andrew. I understood your point regarding using the Shift registers. I was reading a bit in the data sheets and understood that I might have to use a SIPO at one end and a PISO at the other end, but that is where I have a problem. I am still thinking on solving it and then maybe I can progress further.

Comment: I read about shift registers, but here's my problem:

I want to check the continuity of wires from point A and B, 50 wires in total. Sometimes the bits would be transferred from A to B and at times from B to A.

If it is normal testing from A to B, then I need a SIPO and a PISO. And that's why I want to use an FPGA to implement these registers. That's the reason of choosing FPGA in the first place.

Is there any other way I can implement the 2 kind of registers in one chip and then select them depending upon high or low bit.

Answer (score 1):

> Also I want to implement a microcontroller function within an FPGA. I
>   know this is possible but just wanted to be sure about it in the case
>   of low cost FPGAs.

It depends how complex the controller is going to be and how fast you want to run it. You pay for size and speed.

> I also want to implement a Digital to Analog amplifier.

FPGAs are digital only.

> I want to use 100 FPGAs and I want to know whether it is possible to
>   have just a single programming board and program all these 100 FPGAs
>   and then use them standalone in my PCB.

Most FPGAs are volatile, they lose their program when power is removed. They normally read their program from a serial ROM on power up or are programmed by a processor every time.

> As FPGAs are cheap but the programming boards are very expensive.

That's an "alternative fact".

> Also I was unable to find through-hole FPGAs

That's because such a thing is an odd idea. You use FPGAs when you need to fit a lot of logic into a small area. Why would you then use a massive through hold package when surface mount ones are so much smaller.

Comment: A DAC can be implemented using an R-2R ladder and an op amp buffer.

Comment: But in that situation all of the analog system is external to the FGPA, the FPGA remains a purely digital system. With external electronics you can create an analog signal from virtually any digital system. You could use a PWM output and an RC filter if you wanted. But how to get an analog signal from a digital system is a completely different question and unrelated to FPGAs.